# CSS: background / background-image tamaño fijo

Tags: html, css

Teniendo este código

```
<div>
    <div class="item1 item active">

    </div>
    <div class="item2 item">

    </div>
    <div class="item3 item">

    </div>
    <div class="item4 item">

    </div>
</div>
 .item1{
 height:370px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url('res/images/publi/1.png');
}
 .item2{
 height:370px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url('res/images/publi/2.png');
}
 .item3{
 height:370px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url('res/images/publi/3.png');
}
 .item4{
 height:370px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url('res/images/publi/4.png');
}
```

Y siendo las imagenes de diferentes tamaños, como hago que todos ocupen el mismo espacio sin dejar bordes por los lados o arriba y abajo?

Comment: item1 no esta asociado a nada

Comment: Deberías verificar tus rutas a las imágenes , F12, console verifica si no te arroja errores

Comment: Ya está solucionado, era por la ruta que tiene que ser absoluta, no relativa... pero edito la pregunta porque me ha surgido otra duda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar todo el tamaño del elemento con la propiedad:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Estoy hará que cubra siempre todo el contenido del elemento al que se asigne el fondo, mientras los elementos sean iguales tus imágenes también lo serán.